# handling image and label within cell of a table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

i have created a label and image in each cell of a table view. if image clicked i want the label data referred to that cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *phone=[[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 95, 320,15)]autorelease];

    phone.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [phone setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [phone  setText:[d valueForKey:@"Phone"]];
    [cell addSubview:phone];

    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"call.png"];
    cell.imageView.image=myImageView.image;
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelectedInTable:)];

    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
    [tapped release];
}

-(IBAction)imageSelectedInTable:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"Selected an Image");

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *) [gesture view];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[imgView superview]superview];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Image Tap %@", tappedIndexPath);
}
```

but how to get label data 
thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be several things wrong with your code, like where are you getting "cell" in cellForRowAtIndexPath? That being said, to fix your immediate problem, you could add a tag to your phone label inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, e.g. `phone.tag = 5;` then inside your gesture recognizer method, add `UILabel *phone = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];`. Now you have a reference to the label in that cell.

Comment: i each row i have an image and label. the label data in each row is different